# Should I be worried about this Pumpkin plant discolouration?

Tags: pumpkins

Should I be worried about this Pumpkin plant discolouration?
see pictures:

[image: Pumpkin Plant]
[image: Pumpkin Plant]
[image: Pumpkin Plant]

Comment: There is some lack of fertilizers.

Comment: hmm, I wouldn't have thought so, I was actually concerned about adding too much fertilizer. This is what I have been using: https://www.woodies.ie/westland-1-5kg-fish-blood-bone-1134960?utm_source=google_shopping&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoJW6x-bu3AIVTOd3Ch3GEgq1EAQYAiABEgIgUfD_BwE
But I don't really know, i'm no expert, could i be overwatering?

Comment: It is 3, 9, 3, so very very dilute. Pumpkin requires a lot of N (manure). Check near you for some sort of manure. Often is free or very cheap.

Comment: Oh, The guide i read suggested using a 5,10,5 but i couldn't find one like that in the gardening store and this seemed closest. Since i have this already would it be safe to just use more of it?

Comment: yes. If you use the double, you will have 6,18,6 (if you do not care of total weight). Often I use 27,5,15 (so very high numbers), but I buy it on "agriculture store" in bag of 25Kg or 50Kg (but much much cheap). Just that... N fertilizers are used for terrorism (and dangerous if in contact of fire), so better not to store them in large quantities.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there is some magnesium deficiency here. Lots of information online including pictures of plants with magnesium problems. When doing a search make sure to specify "magnesium deficiency plants" otherwise the search engine will think you mean deficiency in diet. There are also recommendations for a quick remedial solution involving a foliar spray of Epsom salts which might just get your plant going again. Follow the instructions closely.

Also having grass that close will be competition for the pumpkin, which will have a hard time preventing the grass from stealing the nourishment.